# What is the best way to install Python packages?

Tags: python

What is the best way to install Python packages in Ubuntu 11? I am a recent convert to Ubuntu and want to learn best practices.

For context, I am looking to install the tweeststream package, but I did not see it in my Synaptic package manager. Also, I am very new to programming, but I usually can follow along with code samples.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/21027/easy-install-pip-or-apt-get

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think best way for you would be to install Python packaging system like "python-pip". You can install it with Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center.

Pip will allow you to easy install and uninstall Python packages, simply as `pip install package`. 
In your case it would be something like this from terminal:

```
sudo pip install tweeststream
```

Comment: This is fine for simple packages, but not so good for larger packages e.g. numpy

Comment: @hayd: why? Is that related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/595366/using-pip3-installed-python-3-packages-when-apt-installed-packages-exist-too

Comment: @naught101 I think I probably meant scipy, not sure if it's related... looks like pip is too late in the python path. I strongly recommend using anaconda/conda, it's vastly superior to pip IMO.

Comment: IMHO using `sudo pip <anything>` should be used very carefuly. Since [`tweetstream`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweetstream/) isn't in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/), I recommend using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). [tweetstream's `setup.py`](https://bitbucket.org/runeh/tweetstream/src/default/setup.py) requires `anyjson` which _is_ an [Ubuntu Package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=anyjson&searchon=names). Not installing tweetstream in a `virtualenv` may cause other Ubuntu apps dependent on `anyjson` to fail. Troubleshoot hard.

Comment: To repeat: don't use `sudo pip` on Ubuntu. @MarkMikofski: you don't need virtualenv (unless you want it for some specific reason). `python -mpip install --user package-name` can install the package `packafe-name` for the current user. If there are complex (large C extensions) dependencies; you could install them using `apt-get`, to avoid installing build dependencies unless necessary.

Answer (score 51):

*updated: 2019-05-11: This post mostly mentions `virtualenv`, but according to the [Python doc about module installation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/), since Python 3.5 "the use of `venv` is now recommended for creating virtual environments", while `virtualenv` is an alternative for versions of Python prior to 3.4.*

*updated: 2018-08-17: since [conda-4.4.0](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) use `conda` to `activate` anaconda on all platforms*

*updated: 2017-03-27: PEP 513 - `manylinux` binaries for PyPI*

*updated: 2016-08-19: Continuum Anaconda Option*

This is somewhat a duplicate of [easy_install/pip or apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21027/easy-install-pip-or-apt-get).

## For *global* Python packages, use either the Ubuntu Software Center, apt, apt-get or synaptic

Ubuntu uses Python for many important functions, therefore interfering with Python can corrupt your OS. This is the main reason I never use `pip` on my Ubuntu system, but instead I use either Ubuntu Software Center, [synaptic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/synaptic), `apt-get`, or the newer just `apt`, which all by default install packages from the [Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). These packages are tested, usually pre-compiled so they install faster and ultimately designed for Ubuntu. In addition all required dependencies are also installed and a log of installs is maintained so they can be rolled back. I think most packages have corresponding [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) repos so you can file issues.

Another reason to use either Ubuntu packages is that sometimes these Python packages have different names depending on where you downloaded them from. Python-chardet is an example of a package which at one time was named one thing on PyPI and another thing in the Ubuntu repository. Therefore doing something like `pip install requests` will not realize that chardet is already installed in your system because the Ubuntu version has a different name, and consequently install a new version which will corrupt your system in a minor insignificant way but still why would you do that.

In general you only want to install trusted code into your OS. So **you should be *nervous*** about typing `$ sudo pip <anything-could-be-very-bad>`.

Lastly some things are just easier to install using either Ubuntu packages. For example if you try `pip install numpy` to install numpy & scipy unless you have already installed gfortran, atlas-dev, blas-dev and lapack-dev, you will see an endless stream of compile errors. However, installing numpy & scipy through the Ubuntu repository is as easy as...

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy
```

You are in luck, because you are using Ubuntu, one of the most widely supported and oft updated distributions existing. Most likely every Python package you will need is in the Ubuntu repository, and probably already installed on your machine. And every 6 months, a new cycle of packages will be released with the latest distribution of Ubuntu.

If you are 100% confident that the package will not interfere with your Ubuntu system in any way, then you can install it using pip and Ubuntu is nice enough to keep these packages separate from the distro packages by placing the distro packages in a folder called `dist-packages/`. Ubuntu repository has both pip, virtualenv and setuptools. However, I second Wojciech's suggestion to use virtualenv.

## For *personal* Python projects use pip and wheel in a virtualenv

If you need the latest version, or the module is not in the Ubuntu repository then start a virtualenv and use pip to install the package. Although pip and setuptools have merged, IMO pip is preferred over easy-install or distutils, because it will always wait until the package is completely downloaded and built before it copies it into your file system, and it makes upgrading or uninstalling a breeze. In a lot of ways it is similar to apt-get, in that it generally handles dependencies well. However you <s>will</s> *may* have to handle some dependencies yourself, *but since [PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) was adopted there are now `manylinux` binaries at the Python Package Index (PyPI) for popular Linux distros like Ubuntu and Fedora*. <s>for example as mentioned above for NumPy and SciPy make sure you have installed gfortran, atlas-dev, blas-dev and lapack-dev from the Ubuntu repository</s> For example, both [NumPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) and [SciPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy) are now distributed for Ubuntu as `manylinux` wheels **by default** using OpenBLAS instead of ATLAS. You can still build them from source by using the [pip options `--no-use-wheel` or `--no-binary <format control>`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-use-wheel).

```
~$ sudo apt-get install gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-dev python-virtualenv
~$ mkdir ~/.venvs
~$ virtualenv ~/.venvs/my_py_proj
~$ source ~/.venvs/my_py_proj/bin/activate
~(my_py_proj)$ pip install --no-use-wheel numpy scipy
```

See the next section, "You're not in `sudoers`", below for installing updated versions of pip, setuptools, virtualenv or wheels to your *personal* profile using the `--user` installation scheme with pip. You can use this to update pip for your personal use as [J.F. Sebastian indicated in his comment to another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages/116645#comment1097143_95061). [*NOTE: the `-m` is really only necessary on MS Windows when updating pip*.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip)

```
python -m pip install --user pip setuptools wheel virtualenv
```

*Newer versions of pip automatically cache wheels, so the following is only useful for older versions of pip.* Since you may end up installing these many times, consider using wheel with pip to create a wheelhouse. [Wheel is already included in `virtualenv` since v13.0.0](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/changes/#id19) therefore if your version of `virtualenv` is too old, you may need to install wheel first.

```
~(my_py_proj)$ pip install wheel  # only for virtualenv < v13.0.0
~(my_py_proj)$ pip wheel --no-use-wheel numpy scipy
```

This will create binary wheel files in `<cwd>/wheelhouse`, use `-d` to specify a different directory. Now if you start another virtualenv and you need the same packages you've already built, you can install them form your wheelhouse using `pip install --find-links=<fullpath>/wheelhouse`

Read [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html) in the Python documentation and [Installing packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) on the [Python Package Index main page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi). Also [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/), [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) and [wheel](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

## If you're not in [`sudoers`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) and `virtualenv` isn't installed.

Another option to using a virtual environment, or if you are using a Linux share without root privileges, then using either the [`--user`](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme) or [`--home=<wherever-you-want>`](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme) Python installation schemes with Python's `distutils` will install packages to the value of [`site.USERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE) or to wherever you want. Newer versions of pip also have a [`--user`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption--user) option. *Do not use `sudo`!*

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

If your Linux version of pip is too old, then you can pass setup options using [`--install-option`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption--install-option) which is useful for passing custom options to some `setup.py` scripts for some packages that build extensions, such as setting the `PREFIX`. You may need to just extract the distribution and use `distutils` to install the package the old-school way by typing `python setup install [options]`. Reading some of the [install documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) and the [`distutils` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html) may help.

Python is nice enough to add [`site.USERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE) to your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) ahead of anything else, so the changes will only effect you. A popular location for `--home` is `~/.local`. See the Python [module installation guide](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) for the exact file structure and specifically where your site-packages are. *Note*: if you use the `--home` installation scheme then you may need to add it to the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable using [`export`](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) in your [`.bashrc`](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-bashrc.html), `.bash_profile` or in your shell for your localized packages to be available in Python.

## Use [Continuum Anaconda Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads/#_unix) for Math, Science, Data, or Personal Projects

If you are using Python for either math, science, or data, then IMO a really good option is [the Anaconda-Python Distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads/#_unix) or the more basic [miniconda distro](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) released by [Anaconda, Inc. (previously known as *Continuum Analytics*)](https://www.anaconda.com/). Although anyone could benefit from using Anaconda for personal projects, [the default installation includes over 500 math and science packages like NumPy, SciPy, Pandas, and Matplotlib](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_linux-64), while miniconda only installs Anaconda-Python and the conda environment manager. Anaconda only installs into your personal profile, *ie:* `/home/<user>/` and <s>alters your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to prepend Anaconda's path to your personal `$PATH`</s> [recommends sourcing `conda.sh` in your `~/.bashrc` which lets you use `conda activate <env|default is base>` to start anaconda](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) - **this only affects *you* - your system path is unchanged**. Therefore **you do *not* need root access or `sudo` to use Anaconda!** If you have already added Anaconda-Python, miniconda, or conda to your personal path, then you should remove the `PATH` export from your `~/.bashrc`, and update to the [new recommendation](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20), so your system Python will be first again.

This is somewhat similar to the `--user` option I explained in the last section except it applies to Python as a whole and not just packages. Therefore Anaconda is **completely separate from your system Python**, it won't interfere with your system Python, and only you can use or change it. Since it installs a new version of Python and all of its libraries you will need at least 200MB of room, but it is very clever about caching and managing libraries which is important for some of the cool things you can do with Anaconda.

Anaconda curates a collection of Python binaries and libraries required by dependencies in an [online repository (formerly called *binstar*)](https://anaconda.org), and they also host user packages as different "channels". The package manager used by Anaconda, `conda`, by default installs packages from Anaconda, but you can signal a different "channel" using the `-c` option.

Install packages with `conda` just like `pip`:

```
$ conda install -c pvlib pvlib  # install pvlib pkg from pvlib channel
```

But `conda` can do so much more! It can also create and manage virtual environments just like `virtualenv`. Therefore since Anaconda creates virtual environments, the `pip` package manager can be used to install packages from PyPI into an Anaconda environment without root or `sudo`. Do **not** use `sudo` with Anaconda! *Warning!* Do be careful though when mixing `pip` and `conda` in an Anaconda environment, b/c you will have to manage package dependencies more carefully. Another option to `pip` in a conda environment is to use the [conda-forge channel](https://conda-forge.org/), but also best to do that in a fresh conda environment with conda-forge as the default channel. As a last resort, if you can't find a package anywhere but on PyPI, consider using [`--no-deps`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps) then install the remaining dependencies manually using `conda`.

Anaconda is also similar in some ways to [Ruby RVM](https://rvm.io/) if you're familiar with that tool. Anaconda `conda` also lets you create virtual environments with ***different* versions of Python**. *e.g.*: `conda create -n py35sci python==3.5.2 numpy scipy matplotlib pandas statsmodels seaborn` will create a scientific/data-science stack using Python-3.5 in a new environment called `py35sci`. You can switch environments using `conda`. Since conda-4.4.0, this is now *different* to `virtualenv` which uses `source venv/bin/activate`, but previous to [conda-4.4.0](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) the `conda` commands were the *same* as `virtualenv` and also used `source`:

```
# AFTER conda-4.4 
~/Projects/myproj $ conda activate py35sci

# BEFORE conda-4.4 
~/Projects/myproj $ source activate py35sci
```

But wait there's more! Anaconda can also install different languages such as [R for statistical programming](https://www.r-project.org/) from the [Anaconda `r` channel](https://anaconda.org/r). You can even set up your own channel to upload package distributions [built for conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/index.html). As mentioned [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.github.io/) maintains automated builds of many of the packages on PyPI at the [conda-forge Anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge).

## Epilogue

There are many options for maintaining your Python projects on Linux depending on your personal needs and access. However, if there's any one thing I hope you take away from this answer is that **you should never use `sudo pip` to install Python packages**. The use of `sudo` should be a *warning* to you to be extra cautious because you will make system wide changes that could have bad consequences. You have been warned.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I wish I'd read this before I destroyed my system's Python distribution by `sudo`ing around with `pip`. Great writeup, thanks for this information.

Comment: `pip install numpy` should install all the dependencies

Comment: @Timo as I mentioned in the 2017-03-27 update since [PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) was implemented by [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) [numpy binaries are available on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) which are built with OpenBLAS, _ie_: they have the required dependencies. However as a rule, `pip install <package>` will only install Python package dependencies listed in the `install_requires` section of `setup.py`. For example: installing Jupyter will not install Haskell library [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to export Jupyter notebooks as LaTeX, etc

Comment: In contrast `conda install <package>` probably will install all dependencies, including C/C++, FORTRAN, etc., even Haskell libraries, because conda doesn't just manage Python packages like pip, it manages environments. So if you had Anaconda or miniconda then `conda install Jupyter` installs everything in the [recipe's `meta.yml` file](https://github.com/conda-forge/nbconvert-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml#L31), including [the pandoc Haskell library](https://github.com/conda-forge/pandoc-feedstock). For more info see [PyPA](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/)

Comment: Good, but be careful with your wording in `Epilogue`. To install (system-wide or global) Python packages, you need `sudo` as in `$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy`. Do not use `sudo` with `pip` as the first command if not needed, is this what you want to say?

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Novarchibald's addition, it is generally a good idea to create a virtual environment for your python project and install dependencies inside. This allows you to have better control over dependencies and their versions. To set up a virtual environment, enter:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute my_python_project
```

Then, activate it with:

```
cd my_python_project
source bin/activate
```

At this point anything that you install with pip will be kept inside this virtual environment. If you want to install something globally, then you should first exit virtualenv with:

```
deactivate
```

You can find out more about virtualenv [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: Alternatively: using the pip from the virtualenv bin directory (here my_python_project/bin/pip) you maintain that environment, without a need to "activate" it.
Then - using any of scripts installed in the bin is using given virutalenv.
"activate" is only handy to make calls to "python", "easy_install" and "pip" using virtualenv specific bin.

Comment: Python's install docs say to use "pyvenv" to create virtual environments specific to a project; but that virtualenv is a fall back for projects using older python version, https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip.

Comment: Note that the `virtualenv` options `--no-site-packages` and `--distribute` are deprecated nowadays and have no effect any longer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Zetah'a answer, command to install python-pip from terminal is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
[A GUI framework for PIP developed using PyQt4](https://pypi.org/project/pip-gui/)

A GUI framework for PIP developed using PyQt4

#### The Start Screen

[image]

The start screen contains options for a user to select the process he wants to be carried out.

One can also specify the version of python he wants the operations to be performed upon.

The file menu has an option to "Exit" (shortcut: Ctrl+Q) and "Refresh Lists" which refreshes the resources files containing package data.

#### The Installation Screen

[image]

The installation screen has a search bar which the user can use to search and install desired package(s).

#### The Update Screen

[image]

The update screen displays the list of packages which are out-of-date and can be upgraded.

#### The Uninstall Screem

[image]

The uninstall screen displays the list of packages which are installed in the user's system and can be uninstalled.

#### The Progress Window

[image]

The progress window is an built-in terminal widget for PIP-GUI which displays the processes running while performing operations.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.