# Trouble with pip on 14.04

Tags: upgrade, bash, pip

I am trying to install a few different things and having issues.

I thought pip could have been the issue on one of the packages I was trying to install. So I decided to try to upgrade pip, following this reference:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip

So I ran :

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

That output was:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=172eb5abab25a5e0f7a7b63c7a49378d
  Downloading pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB): 1.1MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

Now however when I run:

```
pip install <package>
```

I get:

```
"bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory"
```

**What can I do to get the new pip working?** 
(And hopefully not have to re-install all of the packages that the older version of pip had installed).

I am very new Ubuntu and to using pip.

*Additional*:

I tried running:

```
easy_install pip
```

This gave me:

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 6.1.1
Adding pip 6.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.4 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

Still the pip command is not being recognized.

```
pip --version

bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

*More additional*:
I downloaded the get-pip.py and then ran python get-pip.py.
This gave me an error something like "InsecurePlatformWarning"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to install python packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the package from the repository,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

If this gives you errors, you might first want to do a

sudo apt-get remove python-pip

and then try again with install.

This also shouldn't interfere or remove the modules you already installed.

Comment: The first line seems to have done the trick. Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have upgraded pip you only needed to update your link to your new pip on /usr/bin

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/
```

since the *old* one has been removed when you upgrade the pip package using pip ;-)

Then, you are ready to go :)

Answer (score 1):

This is merely an issue of bash remembering where executables are located. The Ubuntu python-pip package installs the pip executable to `/usr/bin/pip`, but anything installed via pip goes to `/usr/local`, meaning it installs the pip executable to `/usr/local/bin/pip`. However, bash remembers that the command `pip` is located at `/usr/bin/pip`, because it has looked up the command before, and tries to execute that without actually searching the path.

You can fix this by running `hash -r` in all open bash shells, or by opening a new shell, or rebooting. Reinstalling the Ubuntu python-pip package means you will have two different versions of pip installed simultaneously - but `/usr/local` will be used before `/usr`, so it ends up working. It's just not an efficient way to do things. :)

Comment: I like your certainty, but I actually still *have* a `/usr/bin/pip` in addition to `/usr/local/bin/pip`, for whatever reason.  So folks should check that it actually exists.   Run `which -a pip` and `type pip` to see how many there are, and if it's actually "remembering" the old location.

Comment: The OP did not have a `/usr/bin/pip`. Installing the python-pip package, which installs `/usr/bin/pip`, "fixed" the OP's issue.