# Install PyMC on Amazon EC2

Tags: installation, upgrade, python

I want to use PyMC on Amazon EC2. According to [my package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pymc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) the python-pymc package is only available under *raring*. However, EC2 seems to be shipped with *precise* and after running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it seems to have remained *precise*.

What can I do to install PyMC?

Comment: I had to discover, that Amazon offered pre-installed raring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, `dist-upgrade` does not change the version of Ubuntu - it's just a modified upgrade task that will add and remove packages if required (`upgrade` won't). If you want to move to a newer release look at `do-release-upgrade`.

Second, and more relevantly, if you're using a Python stack, and you depend on having certain versions of parts of that stack, after years of testing [I would strongly recommend using pip and virtualenv](https://askubuntu.com/a/21031/449) to containerise your whole Python environment.

It's a bit more learning but a lot less stress when the underlying Ubuntu does change.

Installing PyMC in a virtualenv is a bit more than a `pip install` but not much more:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython python-dev gfortran libatlas-base-dev build-essential
# activate your virtualenv now
pip install matplotlib scipy numpy networkx nose pymc
```

Note this is just one of a hundred million different ways of installing this manually. For simplicity you could just install straight into Ubuntu's system site packages. It's a similar process but you can offload most of the packages to Ubuntu repo packages instead.