# After PIP install --upgrade Dpkg still lists old python packages

Tags: upgrade, package-management, python, dpkg

I recently upgraded all python data analysis tools using pip.  When I do

```
dpkg -l |grep python
```

I see the old version numbers of the software I just upgraded via pip.

How can I ensure that the dpkg list reports the correct versions? 
*(I assume dpkg -l needs to be correct)*

For example, I upgraded ipython to version 1.0.0 using pip; however, dpkg reports version 0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the same if you use dpkg instead of pip. The first is a package manager for Debian based systems and provides means to handle packages and install packages from the [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) made by package teams. PIP handles Python only packages and installs them from the cheese shop [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

The two methods differ to the versions which they install with PIP always installing the newest package version.

One method to list all installed packages is to install and use [yolk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk/0.4.3): `sudo pip install yolk` and then issue `yolk -l` to list all packages.

Other methods are mentioned at the following SE question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/739993/307826

Also these two questions talk about the difference of apt-get - pip for installing Python packages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6874527/307826
- [easy_install/pip or apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/q/21027/12218)

Comment: I realize now that I should have created a virtualenv for my pip upgrades instead of upgrading the main python installation.  Then I would not have to worry about dependency issues due to unknown versions in the main python install on my system.

Comment: While virtualenv and similar tools are not mandatory, it is a good practice to keep your system's Python in good condition.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at two different package managers. DPKG/APT installs in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` (note `dist` - it comes with the distribution) and `pip`/`easy_install` installs in other Python paths.

Both package managers are independent. Your Python application will use the version of the package first in the Python Path. Check your Python path with:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```