# Is it good practice to upgrade .deb packages with pip?

Tags: installation, apt, upgrade, python

It seems [some](http://mirnazim.org/writings/python-ecosystem-introduction/) [blogs](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/) recommend installing pip and setuptools(actually distribute on Ubuntu) with:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-setuptools
```

And then upgrading them with:

```
    $ sudo pip install -U pip
    $ sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

This has some advantages compared to installing them with `ez_setup.py` and `get-pip.py`. For example if I install a package that depends on pip/setuptools with apt-get, it won't try to install the old versions of them because as far as it is concerned they are already installed.

What I want to know is, will this cause any trouble for me in the future (ex: when upgrading Ubuntu to a newer release)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is safer to use .deb packages, in Python this may be so true since there is the [VirtualEnv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) solution and the preferred PIP packager downloading packages from the official repositories ([PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi))

Using VirtualEnv and  PIP you keep your system's Python installation clean since you can install packages with PIP inside virtualenv, in case something goes wrong, you can delete the virtualenv and start over.

Additionally moving packages between virtualenvs is very easy with PIP since PIP can export the installed packages in a text file ([see requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html)) and can import them back in a clean Python system.

You may want to see the following answers - question talking about PIP, dpkg, apt-get and other distributing solutions:

- [After PIP install --upgrade Dpkg still lists old python packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/334248/12218)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6874527/307826
- [easy_install/pip or apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/q/21027/12218)

Comment: The problem is virtualenv is also outdated and will install the same outdated versions of pip and setuptools. Which wouldn't be so bad if some of the packages I use didn't need `setuptools>=0.7`.

Comment: So I'll have to upgrade them manually each time I create a virtualenv (which I do often) and I often forget upgrading them, which causes the installation of some packages to fail.

Comment: I am afraid so, but with PIP it is easy to do so.

Comment: OK. I have solved my problems by writing a script that auto-upgrades setuptools & pip and adding it to virtualenvwrapper's postactivate hook. I'll accept your answer now.

Comment: @mcsofake please, if you could add a reference to the script so the answer could be complete.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/DgsHtR7x. Add `python [path-to-script]` to your `$HOME/.virtualenvs/postactivate`.