# How to install python3-django in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python3, django

`python3-django` is a package available in the repos for Ubuntu 15.04. It isn't in the default repos for Ubuntu 14.04. How can I install it in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to install the latest version of Django globally, a better option is to use pip, the Python package manager. First, you need to install the pip package manager. Refresh your apt package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install pip. If you plan on using Python version 3, install using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Now that you have pip, we can easily install Django. If you are using Python 3, you can type:

```
sudo pip3 install django
```

You can verify that the installation was successful by typing:

```
django-admin --version
1.7.5
```

The [Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

> Now, whenever you start a new project, you can create a virtual
>   environment for it. Start by creating and moving into a new project
>   dire

ctory:

```
mkdir ~/newproject
cd ~/newproject
```

> Now, create a virtual environment within the project directory by
>   typing

:

```
virtualenv newenv
```

> To leave your virtual environment, you need to issue the deactivate
>   command from anywhere on the system:

```
deactivate
```

You can verify the installation by typing:

django-admin --version